How to make jsonb ColumnTransformer compatible with H2
We use jsonb ColumnTransformer with the backend postgres database, how do I make this compatible with h2 so that its possible to run tests in H2 instead of postgres
@JsonProperty("home_address")
@Column(name = "home_address", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
@Convert(converter = JsonbConverter.class)
private Map<String, Object> homeAddress;

EDIT
        address jsonb,

)" via JDBC [Unknown data type: "JSONB";]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createTables(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createSequencesTablesConstraints(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429)


What problem do you have now that prevent you from running your tests?

jsonb is not compatible on h2 embedded database

I've updated with the error which I see on H2

Update version of h2. Latest version support it.
Set MODE=PostgreSQL.
You can do it by adding to connection string
jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;MODE=PostgreSQL


I used 2.3.232 version of h2 and it still doesn't work

It works for me, make sure you set MODE correctly.

I get this Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "JSONB"; SQL statement:

What SQL query you try to execute?

@user352290 Are you sure you set MODE=PostgreSQL?

If application uses Spring Boot, automatic configuration of test databases needs to be explicitly disabled, otherwise custom JDBC URL for H2 with compatibility settings will be ignored.
